# How to exclude particular field name in gson

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I am building json for highchart using gson api.

```
"series": [
    {
      "name": "tesT",
      "data": [["1",12345678], ["2",4534534], ["3",2345678], ["4",456345], ["5",342342]]
    }
  ]
```

My pojo class is

```
public class Series {

    private String name;

    private List<Data> data; // Not working

   // getters and setters
}

public class Data {
   private  String name;

   private Double value;

  // getters and setters
}
```

I am getting the output for data like `[[name: "1", value: 12345678],[name: "2", value: 4534534]...]`.

Expected output is `[["1",12345678], ["2",4534534]....]`.

What datatype i should use for the data attribute in the Series class?

Comment: Don't  use List as raw container... what is data for a type?

Comment: Data contains String, Double for ex ["abc",0.12345678]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is two dimensional array.

Since i am having two different datatypes inside the two dimensional array i have used Object[][]

```
public class Series {

    private String name;

    private Object[][] data; 
// getter and setter
}
```

It works like a charm!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class with a String and a double as data type   and define the your list as a holder of that class.

I.e.
`public class MyData {
    private String nameString;
    private Double myDouble;
    ....
    ....
}`

And in the class Series:
`private List<MyData> data;
....`

Comment: I tried it is not working... Gson will convert like [stringfieldname : "ABC", Doublefieldname : 0.12345678]…… but I need without the fieldnames